# VBA: Replacing characters like * or &

Tags: excel, vba, replace, find-replace

I'm using code below

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).EntireColumn.Replace what:="&^%", replacement:="LOL"
```

Data(in cell(2,2)): `Sometext&^%, just for example`

Expected: `SometextLOL, just for example`

Actual Result: `LOL, Just for example`

Even the excel "Find and Replace" behaves the same way.
Is it considering the "what" text as regular expression? If so how to overcome this.

Comment: Trap the text upto the ampersand first...

Comment: Escape the `*` with `~`

Comment: see https://superuser.com/questions/458606/how-to-search-for-question-mark-in-excel

Comment: @chrisneilsen Wow. Thanks a lot Chris. That worked well. Looks like any string when prepended with ~ behaves like text alone. Thanks again Chris.

Comment: Thanks @larrydahooster for making the question pretty clear and clean. Also please mark it as solved. I don't know how to do.

Comment: @chrisneilsen -You need to supply an answer so the OP can mark it as the answer. Right now you answered with just a comment